# Unable to visualize junk character

Tags: sql, database, teradata, informatica

I am receiving data input from a .DAT file to my teradata table using Informatica. However it is failing on junk character issue.

**My solution -**

Remove the junk character using a REPLACE function. I tried to open the .dat file in NOTEPAD++ to see what is the junk/bad character but I see this (few samples)

```
Creave Cloud 
Mulple
```

**Image of how it looks in NOTEPAD++**

[image]

The text it shows is **xEDxAFx80 xEDXB6X9F**

**My ask -**

I don't know what these character mean. Can anyone tell me the ASCII code or how to put this in a **REPLACE** function so I can replace it with another character ?

EDIT -

```
Target column_name -  COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(240) CHARACTER SET UNICODE NOT CASESPECIFIC [Teradata Database]
Source Column_name - VARCHAR2(240) [ORACLE Database]
```

**Data in Oracle -**

[image]

Comment: Could you make sure which  `encoding` format are you using in your .dat file? if this is the case try UTF-8

Comment: Strange, looks like `ti` messed up, doesn't seem to be valid Unicode. What is the datatype of that column and the source encoding? And what is returned by `char2hexint(col)`?

Comment: @dnoeth VARCHAR2(240) is the source datatype. It is oracle system. When I use char2hexint I get some hex numbers.

Comment: And the encoding in Oracle, UTF-8? In Teradata, LATIN or UNICODE? Of course `char2hexint` returns hex numbers, what exactly is returned? ANd what's the data in Oracle?

Comment: @dnoeth It is UNICODE in Teradata. These records aren't inserted in the table so no way to check char2hexint function. Added how it looks in Oracle

Comment: Then those junk characters are created by Oracle, you better fix the source first. Of course there's no ASCII code, try the `UNISTR` function.

Comment: @dnoeth I agree it should be fixed from source table but I want to fix this from recieving end too.

Comment: Try Teradata's Unicode Tool Kit to fix malformed Unicode and/or replace illegal characters: http://downloads.teradata.com/download/tools/unicode-tool-kit

Comment: The output in notepad++ already tells you what the ascii characters are, just in hexadecimal form. You can look this up on a hex character site, there are a number on the web. If you want the decimal (ascii number) equivalent then use following query in Oracle, SELECT DUMP(FIELDNAME,1010)  FROM TABLENAME; but you'll still need to look the result up. This will be a multiple byte character so where alphabetical characters only take up one bit, this will be 2 characters made up of 3 bytes each... and there are more of them wherever you would expect to find ti so must be a foreign character set

Comment: I'd recommend www.utf8-chartable.de to search for the characters in UTF-8 i.e. ed af 80 and ed b6 9f but they just look like garbage

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the character using an xml parser or to an xml target and the junk character will get converted to its hex representation thus not erroring out. However, Nico has provided a simpler solution here 
https://network.informatica.com/thread/20642